# Start Download task when GCM message received

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

Once a device receives a GCM message, I'd like my app to contact my server to refresh its content and download new items. I currently have a `GcmListenerService` that receives my GCM messages. How would I go about initiating a download on a new thread, and ensuring my Service isn't completed before my download is finished? I already have a custom helper class where I initiate my downloads on a background thread, that normally runs when my app is opened. I'd like to reuse this helper class to initiate the download from the GcmListenerService. How would I tell my GcmListenerService to not finished until my download completes?

Also, I want to make sure that if my app is opened during the download operation, I can hook in to listening for the download completion from my main activity (hence why I want to use my download helper class).

Comment: You can use an IntentService likes @aleksamarkoni suggests to start the download in the background even your app is not running. When the download is finished, you can save the data into some data storage likes SQLite and it will be automatically processed whenever your app is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell GcmListenerService to not complete. onMessageReceived() in the GcmListenerService should not be blocked for to much time.

The best option is to start your own service, for example IntentService from the onMessageReceived() and then when it gets the new data, you can send order broadcast to your application, it will pick it up if it's running, and then it can fetch the new data, and if your application is not running, that is it did not processed the broadcast you can start your application.